# How to read data from a file with double delimiter on spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delimiter

Could someone please help, how to handle this case.

PySpark Code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, types

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName('read csv').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
df = spark.read.option('delimiter', ',').csv('filename')
```

#Error:
error more than 1 character.

Comment: Can you post sample records from your csv file?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a similar issue. please try with below, see if that works. Please feel free to make changes to the code based on ur data format.

'''#PySpark Code.

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, types

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName('read csv').getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext

#df = spark.read.option('delimiter',',').csv('filename')

df = spark.read.text('filename')

header = df.first()[0]

schema = header.split('~~')

df_input = df.filter(df['value']!= header).rdd.map(lambda x: [0].split('~~')).toDF(schema)
'''